# sql parameters for date and time

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to run a query that returns values based on yesterday's date. In this case how many items were shipped out yesterday. This is my query:

```
shh.SHIP_DATE = dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())
```

when I run it it doesn't return anything, but when I plug in a date it gives me values:

```
shh.SHIP_DATE = '2013-12-09'
```

Comment: That's not a query. Where's your real code?

Comment: The full code is SELECT *

FROM

zzoshprh AS shh INNER JOIN zzoshprd AS shd ON shh.PKEY = shd.fkey
WHERE     

 (shd.line_status = 'I') AND (shh.CUSTOMER IN ('norhteast', 'southeast')) 
    AND (shh.CONF_TYPE = 'A') 
    AND (shd.style <> 'GIFTBOX') 
    AND (shh.SHIP_DATE = dateadd(dd, -1, getdate()))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `SHIP_DATE` column a date or a datetime? I'm assuming it's a datetime column, but storing only a date value, so when you use getdate() you are going to get the time value as well. You could easily get it working by using the predicate `(shh.SHIP_DATE = cast(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate()) as date))`

Comment: perfect thank you. I couldn't figure out how to get rid of the time portion.

Answer (score 0):

`GETDATE()` includes the current time as well.  You need to truncate the time portion.  There's lost of ways to do that - here's one:

```
shh.SHIP_DATE = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate())-1, 0)
```

translated - add one less than the number of days between date "0" and today to date "0"

Comment: this worked as well. tried both answers. thank you for your help.